# Swift 5: Why Range<String.Index>.Bound.utf16Offset calculates offsets even if empty string provided as argument

Tags: swift

In Swift 4 I had a function to dump Range to debugger output defined as below:

```swift
extension Range where Bound == String.Index {

   public func dump() -> String {
      return "[\(lowerBound.encodedOffset)..<\(upperBound.encodedOffset)] (\(length))"
   }

   public var length: Int {
      return upperBound.encodedOffset - lowerBound.encodedOffset
   }
}
```

Since in Swift 5 `encodedOffset` is deprecated I changed implementation as below:

```swift
extension Range where Bound == String.Index {

   public func dump(string: String) -> String {
      let lower = lowerBound.utf16Offset(in: string)
      let upper = upperBound.utf16Offset(in: string)
      let result = "[\(lower)..<\(upper)] (\(upper - lower))"
      return result
   }
}
```

Test working as expected after implementation update:

```swift
class RangeTests: LogicTestCase {

   func test_dump() {
      let string = "Hello!"
      let range = string.range(of: "ello")
      Assert.equals(range?.dump(string: string), "[1..<5] (4)")
   }
}
```

But function `dump` works correctly even if empty string is passed:

```swift
class RangeTests: LogicTestCase {

   func test_dump() {
      let string = "Hello!"
      let range = string.range(of: "ello")
      Assert.equals(range?.dump(string: ""), "[1..<5] (4)")
   }
}
```

Shouldn't, for instance, call to `lowerBound.utf16Offset(in: "")` throw exception because we passing empty string, while range itself not empty?

---

**UPDATE 1**:

With the trick, with `lowerBound.utf16Offset(in: "")` mentioned above, the following two versions of sample index shifting function works identically:

```swift
extension String.Index {

   // Deprecated due `encodedOffset`
   public func shifting(by offset: Int) -> String.Index {
      return String.Index(encodedOffset: encodedOffset + offset)
   }

   // Possible Swift 5 replacement to achieve index manipulation
   // without reference to string. 
   public func shifting(by offset: Int) -> String.Index {
      let newOffset = utf16Offset(in: "") + offset
      let referenceString = String(repeating: " ", count: newOffset)
      let result = String.Index(utf16Offset: newOffset, in: referenceString)
      return result
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't use encoded offset, use string distance method. Try `"".lastIndex(of: "")?.encodedOffset` it returns 4

Comment: why don't you use the range `count` property ?

Comment: `range.count` cause error `Type 'String.Index' does not conform to protocol 'Strideable'` :0

Comment: my bad. You need an instance of the String to calculate the distance

Comment: `let string = ""
let range = string.startIndex..<string.endIndex
let distance = string.distance(from: range.lowerBound, to: range.upperBound)
print(distance)  // 3`

Comment: That is clear that proper way to calculate indexes and ranges - is by using string as reference. But still want to know why expression like `utf16Offset(in: "")` calculates offsets properly even if reference sting is fake "empty sting".